# A4J:support doesn't work when javascript event is setted into h:inputText

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm maintaining a JSF legacy system and I have a following problem:
There is a:inputText component with events onchange, onkeyup and onkeydown triggering javascript function, like this:

```
<h:inputText id="idX" 
    value="#{myBackingbean.myProperty}"
    maxlength="14" size="14"
    onkeypress="return javascriptMethodOne(event);"
    onkeyup="javascriptMethodTwo(this, 1), javascriptMethodThree('idX','other_ID',14,event);"
    onchange="javascriptMethodTwo(this, 1); javascriptMethodFour(JS_CONST);" />
```

I need call a backing bean method from h:inputText and I thought add a a4j:support into h:inputText, like this code:

```
<h:inputText ... >
    <a4j:support .../>
</h:inputText>
```

The problem is a4j:support doesn't work when events are setted in componet h:inputText.

So, keeping the calls of javascript functions, how I can do to call a backing bean method when onchange, onkeyup or onkeydown is triggered?

The following code doesn't work:

```
<h:inputText id="idX" 
    value="#{myBackingbean.myProperty}"
    maxlength="14" size="14"
    onkeypress="return javascriptMethodOne(event);"
    onkeyup="javascriptMethodTwo(this, 1), javascriptMethodThree('idX','other_ID',14,event);"
    onchange="javascriptMethodTwo(this, 1); javascriptMethodFour(JS_CONST);">

<a4j:support action="#{myBackingbean.myMethod}" event="onchange"/>

    <a4j:support action="#{myBackingbean.myMethod}" event="onkeyup"/>

    <a4j:support action="#{myBackingbean.myMethod}" event="onkeydown"/>

</h:inputText>
```

Thx!

Comment: You can use `a4j:jsFunction`. Also ALWAYS write about your libraries, no one wants to guess that you are using RF 3.X which is deprecated for over 7 years now.

Comment: Thank you!!! I simply forgot about this option!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help ;-)